# Block django allauth default signup/login url

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am rendering my django-allauth signin/signup form through custom URLs.

```
from allauth.account.views import LoginView, SignupView 

urlpatterns = [
   ...
   url(r'^customurl/login/', LoginView.as_view(), name="custom_login" ),
   url(r'^customurl/signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name="custom_singup" ),
   ...

]
```

These are working fine. The problem is django-allauth default singin/singup urls working also.
How can I block default signin/signup URLs?

Comment: The default urls should not be available unless you add them to your urlconfig. If you have included this in your urls.py, that's probably why the default urls are working `path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),`. If you need more routes than the two you have now, you can look at django-allauth's urls.py to see which views and routes are expected to be available: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/urls.py

Comment: you may need to remove Django admin urls from urls.py. Or covering Django admin login urls by add `admin/login` url after including admin urls.